# Is a parallel sub-bundle of the normal bundle invariant under ambient parallel-transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am having trouble proving this, it seem obvios to me but i dont know how to prove it:

Let $M$ be a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$  with the induced metric  and let $N_1$ be a sub-bundle of the normal bundle that is parallel in the normal bundle, with that  i mean the normal connection vanishes $\nabla_X ^\bot \eta = 0 $ for every section $\eta \in N_1$ and every $X$ tangent to $M$.

Then i take and arbitrary vector $\eta_p \in (N_1)_p$ where $p$ is an arbitrary point of $M$ and  consider the parallel transport of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of $\eta_p$ along a curve in $\gamma$ in $M$ .

Is true that $\eta(t) \in N_1(\gamma(t))  $ ?

Comment: Parallel transport in the ambient space $\Bbb R^n$ no more agrees with parallel transport in the normal bundle than it does with parallel transport in the tangent bundle. In particular, $\eta(t)$—as you've defined it (I *think*)—is very unlikely even to be normal to the curve at $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: i see, is my definition of normal-parallel transport right? or do you think i should change it?

Comment: So are you asking if $N_1\subset N$ is the analog of a totally geodesic submanifold? That if you parallel translate in $N$, starting with an element of $N_1$, then you stay in $N_1$? ... But, yes, you have not properly described parallel translation in the normal bundle.